# Cant map through props - React JS/API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to populate a list from an API call/search on a react app. Getting the error that property "map" is undefined in Main.js where the movieList is being called. Application runs until you try and type into the search box. Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here??

App JS:

```
function App() {
  const [movieList, SetMovieList] = useState([]);
  const [search, SetSearch] = useState("");

  const HandleSearch = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        FetchMovies(search);
    }

  const FetchMovies = async (query) => {
    const temp = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/=${query}`)
      .then(res => res.json());

        SetMovieList(temp.results);
    }

<div className="content-wrap">
          <Sidebar nominations={nominations}/>
          <Main
            HandleSearch={HandleSearch}
            search={search}
            SetSearch={SetSearch}
            movieList={movieList}
            />
      </div>
```

Main JS:

```
<main>
            <div className="main-head">
                <form className="search-box"
                    onChange={props.HandleSearch}>
                    <input
                        type="search"
                        placeholder="Search the OMDB database..."
                        required
                        value={props.search}
                        onSubmit={e => props.SetSearch(e.target.value)}/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="movie-list">
                {props.movieList.map(movie => (
                    <MovieCard
                        movie={movie}
                        key={movie.mal_id} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Can you log movieList in main.js and check if it is an array?

Comment: It does return an empty array if you log it.

Comment: `  const FetchMovies = async (query) => {
    const temp = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/=${query}`)
   return temp.json();
    }`
    
    `  const HandleSearch = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        FetchMovies(search)
      .then(data=> SetMovieList(data));
    }`

Comment: try to use postman see what data you have from the api. and then in your code see what you have in `FetchMovies ` function. not sure what ` fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/=${query}`)
      .then(res => res.json());` return

Comment: It returns the correct data, an array of all movies with the query, which is being fed from the search function. I can log the correct searches if I remove the movieList map function, but I can't get them to display on the page.

Comment: is `FetchMovies(search);` triggered properly? what is the value of `search` when `HandleSearch ` is executed?

Comment: It is better if you could add a sample of response data to the question that you're getting from the API.

Comment: {
    "Search": [
        {
            "Title": "Batman Begins",
            "Year": "2005",
            "imdbID": "tt0372784",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTY4YjI2N2MtYmFlMC00ZjcyLTg3YjEtMDQyM2ZjYzQ5YWFkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },

Comment: That is the log from the app when I remove the map function and just type "bat" and enter.

Comment: `{props.movieList&&<div className="movie-list">
                {props.movieList.map(movie => (
                    <MovieCard
                        movie={movie}
                        key={movie.mal_id} />
                ))}
            </div>}` try this

Comment: is that the log from `console.log(temp.results)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the movieList is undefined or empty.
Try to check whether it has data or not with conditional operator:

```
<div className="movie-list">
 {props.movieList ? props.movieList.map(movie => (
    <MovieCard
       movie={movie}
       key={movie.mal_id} />
 )) : {}
 }
</div>
```

Comment: Produces; Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Try re-writing your fetch API statement like this: 
    `const temp = await fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/=${query}')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => SetMovieList(data));`